# Lazy form of Tuples/Outer to loop over list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, combinatorics, lazy-computations

This is less a question and more asking if someone has implemented this already, with more skill.

I need to perform the `Outer`-like generalized outer product of a list of lists (also a form of `Tuples`). I need to do it in a lazy way because the lists will become very large (many tens of thousands of elements).

I am using a Module to hold state as iterate over the products

```
loopOver[list0_]:=Module[
  {len0,index,get,increment,isDoneQ,doneB},
  len0=Length[list0];
  Do[index[j]=1,{j,len0}];
  doneB=False;
  get[]:=Table[list0[[j,index[j]]],{j,len0}];
  increment[]:=Block[
    {stack,p},
    If[doneB,Return[]];
    stack={len0};
    While[Length[stack]>0,
     p=First@stack;
     stack=Rest@stack;
     index[p]=index[p]+1;
     If[index[p]>Length[list0[[p]]],
      (
       If[p===1,doneB=True;Return[]];
       index[p]=1;stack=Append[stack,p-1]
       )
      ]
     ]
    ];
  isDoneQ[]:=doneB;
  {
   "get"->get,
   "increment"->increment,
   "isDoneQ"->isDoneQ
   }
  ]
```

And you use it as such:

```
Block[
 {a, get, increment, isDoneQ},
 a = {
   {"11", "12", "13"},
   {"21", "22"},
   {"31"},
   {"41", "42"}
   };
 {get,increment,isDoneQ}=loopOver[a][[All,2]];
 While[!isDoneQ[],
  Print[get[]];
  increment[]
  ]
 ]
```

outputting the expected outer of 3*2*1*2=12 products:

```
{11,21,31,41}
{11,21,31,42}
{11,22,31,41}
{11,22,31,42}
{12,21,31,41}
{12,21,31,42}
{12,22,31,41}
{12,22,31,42}
{13,21,31,41}
{13,21,31,42}
{13,22,31,41}
{13,22,31,42}
```

Code review would be appreciated too. I hope my code is high on self documentation where it is low on performance and use of MMA functional coding style.

Comment: You may find [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85278/is-there-a-built-in-equivalent-to-pythons-enumerate/85336#85336) relevant. There, I have illustrated lazy `Tuples`, from which lazy `Outer` is pretty easy to get. Unfortunately, that answer relies on undocumented functionality, so I can't at the moment recommend it for anything more than an illustration, since it is not based on officially supported features.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that question is already favorited, but not completely mentally digested ;)

Comment: Related: [(9554)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The implementation of lazy tuples [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/56c6fcfe7cafcd73bdf8/raw/LazyTuples.m) pretty much contains the solution to the lazy `Outer` problem. I will take the relevant parts from that code.

The following code constructs a function `take`, which would, given the start and end positions in the flat list of the resulting combinations, extract the elements:

```
ClearAll[next];
next[{left_, _}, dim_] := 
  {left - dim*(# - 1), #} &[IntegerPart[(left - 1)/dim] + 1];

ClearAll[multiDims];
multiDims[dims_] := Rest @ Reverse @ FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse @ dims];

ClearAll[multiIndex];
multiIndex[pos_, dims : {__Integer}] :=
   Rest@FoldList[next, {pos, 0}, multiDims@dims][[All, 2]]

ClearAll[take];
take[lists : {__List}, {start_, end_}] :=
  With[{rend = Min[end, Times @@ Map[Length, lists]]},
    Transpose @ MapThread[
        Part, 
        {lists, multiIndex[Range[start, rend], Length /@ lists]}
    ]
  ];
```

For example,

```
take[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {3, 7}] == Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}][[3 ;; 7]]

(* True *)
```

The difference is of course, that `take` only computes those elements that have been requested, so can be used as a basis for a lazy implementation.

Here is then an implementation of an iterator, that would return consecutive combinations in chunks of specified length:

```
ClearAll[makeTupleIterator];
makeTupleIterator[lists:{__List}, chunkSize_Integer?Positive]:=
  With[{len=Times @@ Length /@ lists},
    Module[{ctr = 0},          
      If[ctr >= len,
        {},
        (* else *)
        With[{taken = take[lists,{ctr+1, Min[ctr+chunkSize,len]}]},
          ctr += Length[taken];
          taken
        ]
      ]&
    ]
  ];
```

Here is an example: we construct an iterator with the chunk size of 10 elements:

```
iter = makeTupleIterator[{{"11", "12", "13"}, {"21", "22"}, {"31"}, {"41", "42"}}, 10];
```

Now we use it:

```
iter[]

(*
{        
    {"11","21","31","41"},
    {"11","21","31","42"},
    {"11","22","31","41"},
    {"11","22","31","42"},
    {"12","21","31","41"},
    {"12","21","31","42"},
    {"12","22","31","41"},
    {"12","22","31","42"},
    {"13","21","31","41"},
    {"13","21","31","42"}
}
*)

iter[]

(* {{"13", "22", "31", "41"}, {"13", "22", "31", "42"}} *)

iter[]

(* {} *)
```

When we get an empty list, this tells us that the iterator has been exhausted.

This basically implements lazy tuples, and therefore also lazy `Outer`, more or less. You gain efficiency by picking large enough chunks, since chunk extraction (`take` function) is pretty fast, compared to the top-level iteration that would be needed to extract element by element.

Comment: Hi, Leonid. Your lazy tuple is so useful. The only problem is the performace is somewhat too slow. for example, let `list=Table[Range[100], 3]`, `Tuples[list]` only takes 0.03 sec. However, to generate full tuple using `iter[]` takes totally 3 sec

Comment: Hi @matheorem. Unfortunately I don't have the time to test right now, but the speed depends also on the chunk size. For a better speed, the chunk size should be large enough. Try chunk size of about 10000 or more, and see if that helps. That said, the built-in version will always be much faster. The point of lazy version is that it does not need to realize all tuples at once.

Comment: I have tested it, I can see there is a limit of chunk size after which further increase chunk size will not reduce timing any more. Though lazy version is destined to be slower than built-in version, but more than hundreds times slower than `Tuples` make it not unpractical to be severed as a general approach to circumvent  memory constraints if we have to traverse all the tuples. Specific method have to be used, for example, my post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124984/4742  wuyingddg provides a solution which is so hard to beat. But this kind of specific solution needs much more wit

Comment: @matheorem Perhaps you are right. I will have to look into it myself to see. There may be faster methods than the one I suggested above.  I will look into it when I get a moment, I just don't know when that would be.

Answer (score 14):

**Overview**

Here is a refinement of @Leonid's approach that is a bit faster. The basic idea is to create a `TuplesFunction` that encapsulates the tuples information, and can be applied to [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) type specs. That is, instead of using:

```
Tuples[lists][[part]]
```

you would use:

```
tf = TuplesFunction[lists];

tf[part]
```

The goal is to make `TuplesFunction[__]` as small as possible, and `TuplesFunction[__][part]` as fast as possible.

**Decompose**

As described in other answers, it is possible to make a function that takes an integer index and the lengths of the lists, and returns the indices of the lists needed to construct the corresponding tuple. The built-in functions that can do this are [`NumberDecompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberDecompose) and [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits) with [`MixedRadix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixedRadix). However, since this is a function that accepts an integer (the index) and a list of integers (the lengths of the lists), and returns a list of integers (the indices of each list needed to construct the tuple), we can use [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile):

```
decompose = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {d, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{c=n, q},
        Table[
            q = Quotient[c, i];
            c = Mod[c, i];
            q,
            {i, d}
        ]
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}
];
```

The function `decompose` is modeled after [`NumberDecompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberDecompose) hence the second argument should be a `basis`, as described in the [`NumberDecompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberDecompose) documentation. Here is a check between `decompose` and [`NumberDecompose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberDecompose):

```
decompose[103, {49, 7, 1}]
NumberDecompose[103, {49, 7, 1}]
```

> {2, 0, 5}
>
> {2, 0, 5}

and a little speed comparison:

```
r1 = decompose[Range[10,100], {49, 7, 1}];//RepeatedTiming
r2 = NumberDecompose[#, {49, 7, 1}]& /@ Range[10, 100]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.000029, Null}
>
> {0.0019, Null}
>
> True

So, compilation definitely helps here. Now, rather than relying on the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute to get decompose to work with lists of    integers, it is possible to create a compiled function that accepts lists:

```
decomposeList = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 1}, {d, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{c=n, q},
        Table[
            q = Quotient[c, i];
            c = Mod[c, i];
            q,
            {i, d}
        ]
    ]
];
```

Let's compare the two compiled functions:

```
r1 = decompose[Range[1000], {10000, 100, 1}]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = decomposeList[Range[1000], {10000, 100, 1}]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === Transpose[r2]
```

> {0.000089, Null}
>
> {0.000057, Null}
>
> True

Even faster, although the returned result is transposed. This actually turns out to be a good thing.

**Index decomposition to tuple**

Next, we need to convert the list of indices into a tuple. In the following examples I use the lists `{Range[10], Range[5], Range[7]}` so that tuples extraction is obvious. For a single list of indices, we can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread):

```
MapThread[Part, {{Range[10], Range[5], Range[7]}, {2, 4, 3}}]
```

> {2, 4, 3}

If we have multiple lists of indices, we can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread) again, but this time we need to transpose first:

```
Transpose @ MapThread[
    Part,
    {
        {Range[10], Range[5], Range[7]},
        Transpose[{{2,4,3}, {5,2,3}, {7,1,2}}]
    }
]
```

> {{2, 4, 3}, {5, 2, 3}, {7, 1, 2}}

**Span support**

One final enhancement. It would be nice to use [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span) in the definition of `TuplesFunction`. To do this, we need a way to convert a [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span) specification to a list of indices. Here is a function to do this:

```
toList[Span[a_, b_, c_:1], max_] := With[
    {
    x = Replace[a, {All->1, UpTo[x_]:>Min[x,max]}],
    y = Replace[b, {All->max, -1->max, UpTo[x_]:>Min[x,max]}]
    },

    Range[x, y, Replace[c, {All -> If[x<=y, 1, -1], Except[_Integer]->1}]]
]
```

A few examples:

```
toList[1 ;; ;; 2, 10]
toList[UpTo[13] ;; -1, 20]
toList[UpTo[23] ;; UpTo[8], 20]
toList[UpTo[23] ;; UpTo[8] ;; All, 20]
```

> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
>
> {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
>
> {}
>
> {20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8}

**TuplesFunction**

Those are the pieces we need to use in the `TuplesFunction` definition. The following code block is complete. It has all the definitions for `TuplesFunction` as well as a summary box format and the earlier definitions for decompose, decomposeList and toList;

```
TuplesFunction[lists_] := With[{lens = Length /@ lists},
    TuplesFunction[
        lists,
        Reverse @ FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse @ Rest @ lens]
    ]
]

TuplesFunction[lists_, basis_][index_Integer] := With[
    {decomp = 1 + decompose[index-1, basis]},

    MapThread[Part, {lists, decomp}]
]

TuplesFunction[lists_, basis_][indices:{__Integer}] := With[
    {decomp = 1 + decomposeList[indices-1, basis]},

    Transpose @ MapThread[Part, {lists, decomp}]
]

TuplesFunction[lists_, basis_][span_Span] := With[
    {r = toList[span, Times @@ Length /@ lists]},

    TuplesFunction[lists, basis][r]
]

MakeBoxes[t:TuplesFunction[lists_List, ___], StandardForm] ^:= Module[
    {lens=Length/@lists},

    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
        TuplesFunction,
        t,
        BarChart[lens,ImageSize->30,Axes->False],
        {
            BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Count: ",Times@@lens}, StandardForm],
            BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Length: ", lens}, StandardForm]
        },
        {},
        StandardForm,
        "Interpretable"->True
    ]
]

decompose = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {d, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{c=n, q},
        Table[
            q = Quotient[c, i];
            c = Mod[c, i];
            q,
            {i, d}
        ]
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}
];

decomposeList = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 1}, {d, _Integer, 1}},
    Module[{c=n, q},
        Table[
            q = Quotient[c, i];
            c = Mod[c, i];
            q,
            {i, d}
        ]
    ]
];

toList[Span[a_, b_, c_:1], max_] := With[
    {
    x = Replace[a, {All->1, UpTo[x_]:>Min[x,max]}],
    y = Replace[b, {All->max, -1->max, UpTo[x_]:>Min[x,max]}]
    },

    Range[x, y, Replace[c, {All -> If[x<=y, 1, -1], Except[_Integer]->1}]]
]
```

Here is an example:

```
tf = TuplesFunction[{Range[4], Range[2], Range[3]}]

r1 = Tuples[{Range[4], Range[2], Range[3]}][[5 ;; 15]];
r2 = tf[5 ;; 15];

r1 === r2
```

> TuplesFunction[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {6, 3, 1}]
>
> True

Here is a timing comparison between using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples) and `TuplesFunction`:

```
r1 = Tuples[{Range[100], Range[100], Range[100]}]; //RepeatedTiming

tf = TuplesFunction[{Range[100], Range[100], Range[100]}]
r2 = tf /@ Partition[Range[10^6], 1000]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === Flatten[r2, 1]
```

> {0.0066, Null}
>
> TuplesFunction[CompressedData["
>   1:eJzt0bVCQgEAQNFnYwN2oIKY2N1gYyt2Kzrr/2+cxdkfeMMZ7nyTxd/CT3kQ
>   BBV8U8ZfV1JFNTVEqKWOehpopIlmosSI00IrbbTTQSdddNNDLwn66GeAJCkG
>   STPEMCOMMsY4GSaYZIppZphljnkWWGSJZVZYZY11Nthkiyw5ttlhlz32OeCQ
>   PEccc8IpZ5xzwSVXFLjmhlvuuOeBR5545oVX3njng0+KfIU/wh/hj39/lADu
>   ED1K
>   "], {10000, 100, 1}]
>
> {0.11, Null}
>
> True

A little over an order of magnitude slower than just using [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples), but the memory footprint is far less. Here is a memory comparison:

```
r1 = Total @ Tuples[{Range[100], Range[100], Range[100]}]; //MaxMemoryUsed

r2 = Sum[Total @ tf[ Span[1000l + 1, 1000(l+1)] ], {l, 0, 999}]; //MaxMemoryUsed

r1 === r2
```

> 24003312
>
> 253096
>
> True

One final example:

```
tf = TuplesFunction[{Range[10^4], Range[10^4], Range[10^4]}];

tf[10^9 -10 ;; 10^9 + 10] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000086, {{10, 10000, 9990}, {10, 10000, 9991}, {10, 10000, 9992}, {10, 
>      10000, 9993}, {10, 10000, 9994}, {10, 10000, 9995}, {10, 10000, 9996}, {10,
>       10000, 9997}, {10, 10000, 9998}, {10, 10000, 9999}, {10, 10000, 
>      10000}, {11, 1, 1}, {11, 1, 2}, {11, 1, 3}, {11, 1, 4}, {11, 1, 5}, {11, 1,
>       6}, {11, 1, 7}, {11, 1, 8}, {11, 1, 9}, {11, 1, 10}}}

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use this simple "trick" :

given you example list :

```
a = {{"11", "12", "13"}, {"21", "22"}, {"31"}, {"41", "42"}};
```

the corresponding `12 (3x2x1x2)` unique combinations correspond also to the unique `12`combinations of the elements position in their respective list:

[image]

(for example here above, for the entry #`9`, `13` is at position `3`in the `{"11", "12", "13"}` list, `21` is at position `1` in its list, ...).

and, these combinations of the positions is another way to write the integers [1-12] in the base form `{3,2,1,2} (* Length/@a *)`.

For example for entry `#9`:

`IntegerDigits[9 - 1, MixedRadix[Length /@ a]] + 1`

> `{3, 1, 1, 1}`

In other words, given the unique integer entry, you get directly the corresponding combination of the elements.

Then we can write the function you need,

```
take[alist_, {start_, end_}] := 
 Table[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[n, MixedRadix[Length /@ alist]], 
     Length@alist], {n, start - 1, end - 1}] // 
   Map[Thread[List[Range@Length@alist, 1 + #]] &] // 
  Apply[Part[alist, ##] &, #, {2}] &

take[alist_] := take[alist, {1, Times @@ Length /@ alist}]
```

and for example :

```
take[a, {4, 6}] // TableForm
```

> ```
> {
>  {"11", "22", "31", "42"},
>  {"12", "21", "31", "41"},
>  {"12", "21", "31", "42"}
> }
> ```

```
take[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {3, 7}] == Tuples[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}][[3 ;; 7]]
```

> `True`

Answer (score 0):

`Outer` itself seems to be able to do this:

```
Flatten[Outer[List, {"11", "12", "13"}, {"21", "22"}, {"31"}, {"41", "42"}], 3]

{{"11", "21", "31", "41"}, {"11", "21", "31", "42"}, {"11", "22", "31", "41"}, 
 {"11", "22", "31", "42"}, {"12", "21", "31", "41"}, {"12", "21", "31", "42"}, 
 {"12", "22", "31", "41"}, {"12", "22", "31", "42"}, {"13", "21", "31", "41"}, 
 {"13", "21", "31", "42"}, {"13", "22", "31", "41"}, {"13", "22", "31", "42"}}
```

Comment: Yes, I am after a version of Outer where the whole list of products doesn't have to be in memory all at once, so it is done lazily. This question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85278/is-there-a-built-in-equivalent-to-pythons-enumerate does a good job of describing the problem.

Comment: `Tuples[]` can alternatively be used in the non-lazy case.