# How to efficiently generate unique combination from several lists

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

For example I have a list

```
data={{1,3,2},{3,2,4},{2,4,3}}
```

sublist of `data` has no duplicate elements.

We know `Tuples[data]` will give all combination of 3 element list.

But I don't want all of them. I want those tuples with no duplicate elements, that is to say, I want

```
Select[Tuples[data], DuplicateFreeQ]
```

The problem is the data list could have many sublist, for example

```
data = Table[RandomSample[Range[20], 5], 15]
(*{{2,14,11,20,15},{16,12,11,4,9},{17,6,15,8,19},{12,17,18,1,8},{7,11,3,2,17},{4,16,12,17,14},{11,15,14,6,3},{11,8,19,10,14},{2,19,12,3,14},{18,17,15,14,3},{19,20,11,12,13},{15,17,12,1,18},{13,18,12,7,6},{18,17,16,11,15},{2,12,16,14,13}}*)
```

Apparantly, `Tuples[data]` will certainly blow away anyone's computer memory. But the acutally result of `Select[Tuples[data], DuplicateFreeQ]` could be much much less.

How to efficiently do this? Is there any built-in Combinatorial function for this job?

---

**Update**

a compile version of wuyingddg's answer, only for `data` of rank 2

```
ff4 = Compile[{{lists, _Integer, 2}, {next, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{i, n, temp, bag = Internal`Bag[Most@{0}]},
   n = Dimensions[lists][[-1]];
   For[i = 1, i <= Length@lists, i++,
    temp = Complement[next, lists[[i]]];
    If[Length@temp =!= 0, 
     Internal`StuffBag[bag, Map[Append[lists[[i]], #] &, temp], 2]]];
   Partition[Internal`BagPart[bag, All], n + 1]], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

timing

```
data = Table[RandomSample[Range[20], 5], 10];
Fold[Function[{lists, next}, 
    Table[Map[Append[e, #] &, Complement[next, e]], {e, lists}]~
     Flatten~1], {{}}, data] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
Fold[ff4, {{}}, data] // Length // AbsoluteTiming

{4.60543, 446796}

{1.80494, 446796}
```

Comment: Does the order matter?  With your first example `data` do you want both `{3,2,4}` and `{2,3,4}`?

Comment: @mikado both order. That is what `Tuples` give. But I think this is not that matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Table[RandomSample[Range[20], 5], 15];
Fold[Function[{lists, next}, 
    Table[Append[e, #] & /@ Complement[next, e], {e, lists}]~Flatten~
     1], {{}}, data] // Length // AbsoluteTiming

(* {178.779, 21925624} *)
```

Here is the code, it took 3 mins to get the result and the maximum memory use during its running is about 11G.

With

```
data2 = Fold[
   Function[{lists, next}, 
    Table[Append[e, #] & /@ Complement[next, e], {e, lists}]~Flatten~
     1], {{}}, data];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> `6833491432=6.36GB`

```
data2[[1]] // Length
```

> `15`

Comment: Thank you wuyingddg. Several months ago, my laptop only has 4GB memory. Now I only has 8GB, so ...

Comment: @matheorem Large list operations require a lot of RAM, if you have a 8gb USB stick with Readyboost, that might help.

Comment: Actually, Running this with clear kernel shows it only using 2.26GB RAM.

Comment: @matheorem the first out is from data, not the generated result.

Comment: @Feyre Yeah, I just notice that, sorry for my stupidness : )

Comment: finally, I understand your algorithm, clever!