# Lazy tuples made from arbitrary lists

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, lazy-computations

I am dealing with Tuples of n lists each having potentially different length:

```
longList = Tuples[list1, list2, ..., listn]:
```

Since I have to iterate over the elements of longList, precomputing of longList becomes a memory issue very quickly. That's why I'm looking for a lazy list implementation where I can access the ith element of longList without precomputing the whole list.

I came across this piece of code which does almost exactly what I want:
[Lazy lists of Tuples and Subsets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9554/lazy-lists-of-tuples-and-subsets)

Unfortunately, it seems to only work with Tuples made from a common list, i.e. tuples taking the form:

```
Tuples[list,n]
```

I wonder wheter there is a way to either adjust the linked code or whether anyone is aware of a solution to this type of problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109598/lazy-form-of-tuples-outer-to-loop-over-list-of-lists?rq=1) answering your question?

Comment: Yes and no @John. I actually implemented one of the suggested solutions but  they work slightly differently. What the solutions in your link do is iterate through all permutations. What I was hoping for was a way to directly access the ith permutation.

Comment: I think the first part of Leonid Shifrin's answer in that link handles what you want.  Specifically `take[listOfLists__,{start_,end_}]` gives you just one element when `start=end`.  Example: `take[{a /@ Range[10^6], b /@ Range[10^6], c /@ Range[10^6]}, {23 10^5,  23 10^5}]` $\mapsto$ `{{a[1], b[3], c[300000]}}`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks a lot! I don't know how I missed this. Do you by any chance see a way to obtain only those tuples where the ith entry is equal to some value y? I.e. all tuples satisfying (x1, x2, ...,x(i-1),y,x(i+1),...).

Comment: Wouldn't that literally be restricting your list of lists to only include the element you're interested in y's parent list?  i.e.   if I only wanted everyone who's second entry was `b[15]`:  `take[{a/@Range[10^6], (b/@Range[10^6])[[{15}]], c/@Range[10^6]}, {start,end}]`

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thank you very much @John, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Based on the comments above I am marking this question as *already has an answer*