# Lazy evaluation of the i-th element of Tuples

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to use `Tuples[tab]` where `tab={vec1,vec2,vec3}` and `vec1,vec2,vec3` are vectors of possibly different lengths `n1,n2,n3`. Therefore, it is:

```
Dimensions[Tuples[tab]] -> {n1*n2*n3,3}
```

Now, if `n1,n2,n3` are large, `Tuples[tab]` occupies a lot of memory. Is it possible not to create `Tuples[tab]` but rather evaluate on demand its i-th element?

**Note added:** Thank you for pointing me to [Lazy form of Tuples/Outer to loop over list of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109598/lazy-form-of-tuples-outer-to-loop-over-list-of-lists); I was not familiar with the terminology "lazy evaluation".
The solution is `LazyTuples` which can be loaded using:

```
Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/56c6fcfe7cafcd73bdf8/raw/LazyTuples.m"]
```

A self-contained answer is:

```
ClearAll[next];
next[{left_, _}, dim_] := {left - dim*(# - 1), #} &[IntegerPart[(left - 1)/dim] + 1];

ClearAll[multiDims];
multiDims[dims_] := Rest@Reverse@FoldList[Times, 1, Reverse@dims];

ClearAll[multiIndex];
multiIndex[pos_, dims : {__Integer}] := Rest@FoldList[next, {pos, 0}, multiDims@dims][[All, 2]]

ClearAll[take];
take[lists : {__List}, {start_, end_}] := With[{rend = Min[end, Times @@Map[Length, lists]]},Transpose@MapThread[Part, {lists, multiIndex[Range[start, rend], Length /@ lists]}]];

take[tab,{i,i}][[1]] (* which gives the same output of Tuples[tab][[i]] *)
```