# Mathematica breaks

Tags: list-manipulation, memory

I write the following command. After running for seconds (less than a minute), Mathematica breaks and nothing is displayed. Why?

```
a = Tuples[{1, I, -I}, {1, 20}]
```

Bests,

Comment: Please don't add [bugs] tag until the community has confirmed it. And, this is definitely not a bug, you're just out of memory: `Table[ByteCount[Tuples[{1, I, -I}, i]]/1024^2., {i, 9, 11}]`

Comment: Thanks. How can I deal with that?

Comment: That depends. Lazy list is a possible choice: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109598/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9554/1871

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (out of memory) and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Comment: You can still [edit] your question and make it about finding a way around the calculation you need. In that case the *hold* would be removed.