# Efficient way to iterate over large list and check conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

The problem I am trying to solve is how to assign charges to a number of particles based on some conditions on the charges. It is conceptually very simple but requires processing a very large list. There are four possible charges: (0,1,2,3), assigned to 19 particles, so there are a total of $4^{19}$ lists of length 19 to loop over. My current attempt uses

```
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 19], C1]]
```

(C1 is some condition), which seems to store all the lists in memory and crashes my computer. Since I only require to check how many possible assignments meet the required condition, I don't need to store any list in memory. What is the most efficient way to iterate over this very large list and solve the problem in a reasonable amount of time? Thanks in advance.

ps. The conditions I want to check are simple conditions like the last three particles having the same charge or the sum of charges of some particles add to zero. For example, C1 is

`C1[charges_]:=Equal@@charges[[{-1,-2,-3}]]`

This is a simple case that can be calculated by hand, but I am trying to combine multiple conditions that make it hard to do so.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to give us an example of the kind of conditions you want to handle.

Comment: Related: [Lazy form of Tuples/Outer to loop over list of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109598/731)

Comment: @CarlWoll Simple conditions like the last three particles have the same charge or the sum of the charges of some particles add to zero.

Comment: It seems to me there should be a way to do what you want without just brute force checking every combination.  Isn't there a way to come up with some formula that would *assign* the value? In other words, you want to only generate those `Tuples` that satisfy the condition, rather than selecting from the entire list those that match the condition.  And *that* requires much more information about what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your criterion functions depend on only a small subset of 19 indices, and that they apply symmetrically to columns (i.e., the number of times a condition `cond` is satisfied on the columns `10, 15`, and `19` is the same as the number of times  `cond` is satisfied on columns `1, 2` and `3` or on any triple of columns) you can write them as functions that take smaller lists as arguments and use `Tuples` (with the number of arguments in the criterion function as the second argument of `Tuples`).

For example:

```
C1[charges_] := Equal @@ charges[[-3 ;;]]
C2[charges_] := Total[charges[[{1, 3, 7, 9}]]] == 5
C3[charges_] := Total[charges[[{1, 9}]]] == 2 Total[charges[[{7, 8, 10}]]]
C4[charges_] := Mean[charges[[{1, 8}]]] == Mean[charges[[{7, 8, 9}]]]
C5[charges_] := {1, 2, 10}.charges[[{1, 2, 10}]] == 31
```

You can re-write `C1` thru `C5` as follows

```
c1 = Equal@@#&;
k1 = 3;
c2 = Total[#] == 5 &; 
k2 = 4;
c3 = Total[#[[;; 2]]] == 2 Total[#[[3 ;; 5]]] &;
k3 = 5;
c4 = Mean[#[[{1, 2}]]] == Mean[#[[{3, 2, 4}]]] &;
k4 = 4;
c5 = {1, 2, 10}.#[[{1, 2, 3}]] == 31 &; 
k5 = 3;
```

To find the number of 19-tuples that satisfy `Cj` we use `cj` to find the number `kj`-tuples that satisfy `cj` (where `kj` is the number of parameters in `cj`) and multiply it with `4^(19-kj)` (this is the number of ways the `19-kj` free columns can be formed):

```
t = 19;
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, k1], c1]] 4^(t - k1)
```

> 17179869184

```
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, k2], c2]] 4^(t - k2)
```

> 42949672960

```
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, k3], c3]] 4^(t - k3)
```

> 10200547328

```
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, k4], c4]] 4^(t - k4)
```

> 21474836480

```
Length[Select[Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, k5], c5]] 4^(t - k5)
```

> 4294967296

**Timings:** for `t = 10` (version 9.0 / Windows10 / 64bit):

```
t = 10;
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], t], C1]] // AbsoluteTiming
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], k1], c1]] 4^(t - k1) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.473403, 65536}
>
> {0., 65536}

```
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], t], C2]] // AbsoluteTiming
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], k2], c2]] 4^(t - k2) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.258324, 163840}
>
> {0., 163840}

```
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], t], C3]] // AbsoluteTiming
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], k3], c3]] 4^(t - k3) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.981313, 38912}
>
> {0.003997, 38912}

```
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], t], C4]] // AbsoluteTiming
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], k4], c4]] 4^(t - k4) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {3.709981, 81920}
>
> {0., 81920}

```
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], t], C5]] // AbsoluteTiming
Length[Select[Tuples[Range[0, 3], k5], c5]] 4^(t - k5) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.311667, 16384}
>
> {0., 16384}

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that you want to compute the total number of possibilities with *multiple* conditions, and that the conditions consist of equality conditions and total conditions, you might want to try using [`SatisfiabilityCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityCount). Since the particles have 4 states, each particle state can be represented by a pair of booleans. For example:

$$\begin{array}{l}
 0\leftrightarrow \{F,F\} \\
 1\leftrightarrow \{F,T\} \\
 2\leftrightarrow \{T,F\} \\
 3\leftrightarrow \{T,T\} \\
\end{array}$$

So, with no conditions we have:

```
vars = Join[Array[a, 19], Array[b, 19]];
SatisfiabilityCount[True, vars]
```

> 274877906944

or

```
4^19
```

> 274877906944

as expected. For the condition that the last three states are identical:

```
SatisfiabilityCount[
    Equivalent[a[17], a[18], a[19]] && Equivalent[b[17], b[18], b[19]],
    vars
]
```

> 17179869184

For the condition that the sum of the first 4 particle states is 5:

```
SatisfiabilityCount[
    Or[
        And[
            BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, 4][a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]],
            BooleanCountingFunction[{2}, 4][b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]]
        ],
        And[
            BooleanCountingFunction[{3}, 4][a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]],
            BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, 4][b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]]
        ]
    ],
    vars
]
```

> 42949672960

In order to combine conditions, it will be convenient to have a function that converts equality and total conditions into the equivalent boolean versions. Let each particle be given the name `p[n]`. Then, a function that converts conditions to equivalent boolean versions is:

```
toBool[Verbatim[Equal][x__p]] := Equivalent @@ apart[{x}] && Equivalent @@ bpart[{x}]
toBool[Verbatim[Plus][x__p] == i_Integer] := With[
    {len = Length[{x}], ap = Sequence@@apart[{x}], bp = Sequence@@bpart[{x}]},
    Or @@ Table[
        BooleanCountingFunction[{j}, len][ap] &&
        BooleanCountingFunction[{(i-j)/2}, len][bp],
        {j, Mod[i,2], i, 2}
    ]
]

apart[{x__p}] := Apply[a, {x}, {1}]
bpart[{x__p}] := Apply[b, {x}, {1}]
```

It is possible to add other kinds of conditions (e.g., `p[1] + 2 p[2] + 3 p[3] == 6`) if desired.

Repeating my previous examples:

```
SatisfiabilityCount[toBool[p[17] == p[18] == p[19]], vars]
SatisfiabilityCount[toBool[p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] == 5], vars]
```

> 17179869184
>
> 42949672960

Here's a more complicated version, designed to produce a low enough count that I can show each of the instances:

```
SatisfiabilityCount[
    toBool[Sum[p[i], {i, 1, 19, 2}] == 4] &&
    toBool[Sum[p[i], {i, 2, 18, 2}] == 2] &&
    toBool[p[1] == p[2] == p[3] == p[4] == p[5] == p[6]] &&
    toBool[p[10] == p[11] == p[12] == p[13] == p[14] == p[15]] &&
    toBool[p[16] + p[17] + p[18] + p[19] == 6],
    vars
]
```

> 9

If you want to find the set of values for the `p[n]` corresponding to the above counts you can use:

```
bools = SatisfiabilityInstances[
    toBool[Sum[p[i], {i, 1, 19, 2}] == 4] &&
    toBool[Sum[p[i], {i, 2, 18, 2}] == 2] &&
    toBool[p[1] == p[2] == p[3] == p[4] == p[5] == p[6]] &&
    toBool[p[10] == p[11] == p[12] == p[13] == p[14] == p[15]] &&
    toBool[p[16] + p[17] + p[18] + p[19] == 6],
    vars,
    All
];
```

Check that we get the same number of instances:

```
Length @ bools
```

> 9

And a function to convert the booleans into `p` values:

```
toP[bools_] := Table[Boole[bools[[i]]] + 2 Boole[bools[[i+19]]], {i, 19}]
```

So, the following are the instances:

```
toP /@ bools //Column //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,2\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,3\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,2,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2\} \\
>  \{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2\} \\
> \end{array}$