# Getting all possible graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I have the following code which gives me some random complete graph

```
rand = {1, 2, 3};
el = EdgeList[CompleteGraph[5]];
g = CompleteGraph[5, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> Table[el[[i]] -> RandomChoice[rand], {i, Length[el]}]]
```

What I want is to get every possible graph with edges labeled with numbers from `rand`.

Comment: I wanna get every graph in some sort of cycle like ```For``` because every iteration I should do something with the graph I've got.

Comment: Are you sure you need all those labeled graphs? Look at the result of `Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 10]`, for instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need all of them since I should counts paths in all this graphs.

Comment: To make the hint in my previous comment more explicit: there are $59049$ of those labeled graphs. If you absolutely must, [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109598) might be of interest.

Comment: I feel like we have 3 possibilities for each edge, and   are there 3^(10*9/2) (=2954312706550833698643) of those labeled graphs?  Of course, a lot of these graphs are isomorphic, and we have to figure out how to get rid of them.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and thought it was 10 vertices.

Comment: @li, an $n$-vertex complete graph has $\dbinom{n}{2}$ edges, which makes for $k^{\binom{n}{2}}$ total labelings for $k$ possible edge labels.