# How to map and sum a list fast?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, functional-style, lazy-computations

The following takes a lot of memory and is slow:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[1, 100000000]]]]
```

I suspect this is because it first calculates and stores the whole list of squared numbers and then performs the summation. At least it would try it, if it wasn't running out of memory (8GB on ubuntu).

On the other hand, Haskell with its lazy evaluation can calculate this:

```
Prelude Data.List> :set +s
Prelude Data.List> foldl' (+) 0 $ map (\x -> x^2) [1..100000000]
333333338333333350000000
(60.08 secs, 74,975,662,856 bytes)
```

It is slow (a whole minute), since this is the interpreter with no optimization, but at least it runs in a constant memory and yields a result.

I am quite sure a couple of years ago I knew the solution, but I forgot.

Answer (score 22):

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Range[1, 100000000]^2]]
(* {26.0686, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

or

```
AbsoluteTiming[#.# &@Range[1, 100000000]]
(* {35.2883, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

or

```
AbsoluteTiming@Total[Range[1, 100000000] /. {x_ -> x^2}]
(* {30.9893, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

To compare with @corey979 solution

```
out = 0;
Do[out = out + i^2, {i, 1, 100000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {95.0359, Null} *)
```

And the winner is ... :)

```
s2[n_] := Sum[i^2, {i, 1, n}]
AbsoluteTiming@s2[100000000]
(* {0.003762, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

Seriously though, the OP's solution is not that slow at all:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[1, 100000000]]]]
(* {27.5232, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

And to imitate Haskell way:

```
AbsoluteTiming@Fold[#1 + #2^2 &, 0, Range[1, 100000000]]
(* {113.901, 333333338333333350000000} *)
```

And to summarize all above, we can have a naive benchmark:

```
d[n_] := First@AbsoluteTiming[#.# &@Range[n]];
t[n_] := First@AbsoluteTiming[Total[Range[n]^2]];
op[n_] := First@AbsoluteTiming@Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[n]]];
re[n_] := First@AbsoluteTiming@Total[Range[n] /. {x_ -> x^2}];

range = {#, 3 #} & /@ (10^Range[3, 7, 1]) // Flatten;
flist = {d, t, op,re};
data = Table[{n, #[n]}, {n, range}] & /@ flist;
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> flist, AxesLabel -> {n, Time}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

So the `d[n]` and `t[n]` were good up to 3 million and the `Dot` is the fastest up to 1 million.

> **Edit**

As @Alan noticed in comments, `s2[n]` behaves strangely. Here is a separate plot for `s2`
[image]

It looks like it actually does summation for small $n$ and then starts using formula ~ $10^6$, so time drops significantly. There is also a jump when $n$ reaches 10^11 but this time the time increases, I guess it's due to the fact that numbers are too big for standard CPU multiplications of integers.

Comment: +you should put the OP's method timing for comparison

Comment: @george2079 I did. Actually I'm quite confused why the `Dot` isn't the fastest.

Comment: I think that your `s2` timing is possibly slightly misleading.  I get a longer time the first time I execute it (`0.0486` seconds) and a faster time (`0.00022` seconds) on subsequent calls.

Comment: @mikado It's not misleading, it's pure cheating. It symbolically calculates the sum for arbitrary $n$ and then plugs 100 000 000 into the formulae. It wouldn't work in general case.

Comment: @BlacKow How can we can we confirm that Mma is behaving as you say (i.e., using the formula)?  The documentation suggests this will not usually be the case, and if you `Trace[Sum[i,{i,1,100}]]` it seems to actually produce all the numbers and sum them up.

Comment: @Alan you can evaluate `s2[a]` and you will get `1/6 a (1 + a) (1 + 2 a)` .. But `Trace` really suggest that you are right... interesting

Comment: @Alan see my edit

Comment: I observe that OP's core complaint is about memory usage, not time.

Comment: @EricTowers that's not what the title says. Also the memory concern is due to MMA failure to compute the sum on OP's computer. I haven't observed such behavior.

Comment: @BlacKow : The title is not the Question.  First words of the Question "The following takes a lot of memory ... ", subsequently, " ... if it wasn't running out of memory ...", and later " ... but at least it runs in a constant memory and yields a result."  OP seems very clear that memory is his concern.

Comment: @EricTowers the only question mark "?" I see is in the title. And it clearly concerns time, not memory. I do appreciate your effort benchmarking memory usage though.

Comment: The tab is labelled "Questions".  The link to post a new question is "Ask Question".  The edit box for replies is labelled "Answers".  Have you never noticed this?  Claiming a Question is not a Question is disingenuous.

Comment: @EricTowers Every question has a title and a body. The title is supposed to express the essence of the question. The body provides explanation of the question, speculations, details etc. If you believe that my answer doesn't address the question you can post your own answer, which you did and I find it very useful. If you believe that my answer is misleading, you SHOULD down-vote it. Calling me disingenuous doesn't add anything to technical aspects that we discuss here.

Comment: Your complaint about your complaint being disingenuous rather assumes, incorrectly, that the title IS the question, and if an answer could have been provided on that basis alone what would have been the point of the body? The title is surely supposed to be the essence but the body must take precedence and I would agree that to ignore the latter is to unhelpfully split hairs.

Answer (score 12):

To overcome the memory issues, let's store as few data in the memory as possible:

```
out = 0;
Do[out = out + i^2, {i, 1, 100000000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
out
```

> {58.7571, Null}
>
> 333333338333333350000000

I observed **100-200 MB memory usage** in the system monitor.

For comparison, the original approach from OP's question:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[1, 100000000]]]]
```

> {11.2087, 333333338333333350000000}

and it ate **5.6 GB of memory**.

---

**EDIT:** Using the parallelized version from [Karsten 7.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127670/22013) I got the result on a 4 core machine in `17.098 seconds` - i.e., 3.44 times faster. I'd expect the parallelized `Do` loop to be faster than the OP's approach on an 8 core machine (not so rare these days). On a $\geq 16$ core cluster the benefit from parallelization would be significant.

Moreover, while [BlacKow's thorough analysis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127660/22013) takes advantage of the structure of the data, in case when the data are e.g. experimental and no such clear pattern is observed, a parallelized `Do` loop might be the most efficient way to handle them.

When memory is crucial, thanks to an [analysis of Eric Towers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127736/22013), it appears that `Do` is the most efficient solution. When it's parallelized, it can also compete when it comes to timing.

---

**EDIT 2:** I don't fully reproduce the behaviour of [BlacKow's `s2` timing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127660/22013):

[image]

---

**EDIT 3:** The best option to compute the sum of squares really fast is to do

```
s2[n_] := Sum[i^2, {i, 1, n}]
s2[a]
```

> 1/6 a (1 + a) (1 + 2 a)

```
sum[a_] := 1/6 a (1 + a) (1 + 2 a)

sum2[n_] := First @ AbsoluteTiming[sum[#]& @ n];

range = {#, 3 #}& /@ (10^Range[1, 20, 1]) // Flatten;
flist = {sum2};
data = Table[{n, #[n]}, {n, range}]& /@ flist;
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> flist, AxesLabel -> {n, Time}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

:P

Comment: well, so far the Do is the most general answer. None of the other solutions can be applied to the general case or runs in a constant memory. However, the whole point was to use a more functional, declarative approach and not to explicitly write Do loops. Haskell does exactly this, summation of a mapped list is ultimately translated to a loop.

Comment: @Yrogirg I listed a Haskell way in my answer, it is basically the same and uses `Fold`, so it even looks similar at least lexically. Unfortunately it uses twice memory because it stores all iterations and then simply returns the very last one.

Answer (score 8):

This addresses the underlying problem, which implies a really fast way is not likely to be found, and shows yet another way to sum a list, [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html).

One reason the OP's sum is slow is that the sum is bigger than a machine integer (which is what I think BlacKow was guessing).  Even the little difference of a few hundred terms makes a big difference in time:

```
Tr[Range[1, 3024600]^2] // Internal`PositiveMachineIntegerQ
Tr[Range[1, 3025000]^2] // Internal`PositiveMachineIntegerQ
(*
  True
  False
*)

AbsoluteTiming[Tr[Range[1, 3024600]^2]]
AbsoluteTiming[Tr[Range[1, 3025000]^2]]
(*
  {0.018311, 9223225016415084100}
  {0.604474, 9226884783646337500}
*)
```

On machine reals, the sum is much faster,

```
AbsoluteTiming[Tr[Range[1., 100000000]^2]]
(*  {0.758036, 3.33333*10^23}  *)
```

although the OP's code is not so much faster,

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[1., 100000000]]]]
(*  {3.76371, 3.33333*10^23}  *)
```

As for memory usage, corey's `Do[]` loop is probably closest to Haskell's lazy version of `Fold`.

Answer (score 7):

Since OP's core complaint appears to be about memory use, I've generated memory usage statistics to match BlacKow's data:

```
d[n_]  := #.# &@Range[n];
t[n_]  := Total[Range[n]^2];
op[n_] := Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[n]]];
re[n_] := Total[Range[n] /. {x_ -> x^2}];
s2[n_] := Sum[i^2, {i, 1, n}];

memUsed[f_, n_] := Module[{
  low, mid, up,
  try
  },
  up = 2^0;
  While[
    MemoryConstrained[f[n], up] === $Aborted,
    up *= 2;
  ];  (* So f[n] requires somewhere in (up/2, up] bytes.  *)

  low = up/2;
  While[up - low > 1,
    mid = 1/2 (up + low);
    try = MemoryConstrained[f[n], mid];
    (*Print[{low,up}, "\t", mid,"\t", try];*)
    If[try === $Aborted,
      low = mid,
      up = mid;
    ];
  ];
up]
```

`memUsed[]` performs an unbounded binary search to find the memory usage.  It is noteworthy that `memUsed[]` results are not stable on multiple calls.

```
memUsed[op, 10^6]
memUsed[op, 10^6]
memUsed[op, 10^6]
(*  24 000 768  *)
(*  24 000 648  *)
(*  24 000 920  *)
```

Perhaps they're "stable enough".

```
range = {#, 3 #} & /@ (10^Range[3, 7, 1]) // Flatten;
flist = {d, t, op, re, s2};
data = Table[{n, memUsed[#, n]}, {n, range}] & /@ flist;
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> flist, AxesLabel -> {n, "Memory"},
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Memory Usage]

For your original range, I get

```
memUsed[op, 10^8]
(*  6 400 000 224  *)
```

6+ GB could be a bit difficult to acquire in an 8 GB environment (depending on what else the computer was doing and whether M'ma requested this memory in large allocations or lots of small ones).

### Edit

Expanded to include Michael E2's `Tr` method and corey979's `Do` method as well as a probably irrelevant variant.

```
Clear[d, t, op, re, s2, tr, do1, do2];
d[n_] := #.# &@Range[n];
t[n_] := Total[Range[n]^2];
op[n_] := Total[Map[#^2 &, Range[n]]];
re[n_] := Total[Range[n] /. {x_ -> x^2}];
s2[n_] := Sum[i^2, {i, 1, n}];
tr[n_] := Tr[Range[1, n]^2];  (* Michael E2's *)
do1[n_] := (out = 0; Do[out = out + i^2, {i, 1, n}]; out) (* corey979's *)
do2[n_] := (out = 0; Do[out += i^2, {i, 1, n}]; out);

range = {#, 3 #} & /@ (10^Range[3, 7, 1]) // Flatten;
flist = {d, t, op, re, s2, tr, do1, do2};
data = Table[{n, memUsed[#, n]}, {n, range}] & /@ flist;
ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotLegends -> flist, AxesLabel -> {n, "Memory"},
  GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Memory used, v.2]

I'm not convinced the differences between `do1` and `do2` are meaningful.

Comment: Pretty cool way of finding memory used! +1

Comment: It will also be interesting to see if solution using Fold uses twice or three times less memory.

Comment: @BlacKow : Michael E2's `Tr` method and corey979's `Do` method (and a probably irrelevant variant) appear in the next  chart (coming in the next edit).

Comment: I just observed that my `Do` uses 100-200 MB of memory. Overly simplifying, it has only a few numbers in memory: the current `out` and the next `i`th step, so I would be extremely surprised if that used a lot of memory.

Comment: @corey979 : Er ..., I don't see 100-200 MB of memory.  `do1` and `do2` nearly completely overlap at all problem sizes at 300-400 bytes used.

Answer (score 7):

Between fast, but memory hungry, vectorized operations represented by `Total[Range[10^8]^2]` and slow, but memory efficient, top level iteration represented by `Do` solution, there's a middle ground. One can generate data in chunks of specified length and use vectorized operations on those chunks. This way you can get constant memory usage dictated by size of a chunk and still have reasonable speed thanks to vectorized operations.

Until [`` Streaming` `` module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85336/14303), that introduces general framework for such operations, is finished and documented, we can implement simple "folding in chunks" by hand.

```
ClearAll[chunkFold]
chunkFold[f_, x_, {min_Integer?Positive, max_Integer?Positive, chunkSize_Integer?Positive, getChunk_}] /; min <= max :=
    Module[{result = x, i},
        Do[
            result = f[result, getChunk[i , i + chunkSize - 1]],
            {i, min, max - chunkSize, chunkSize}
        ];
        f[result, getChunk[min + Quotient[max - min, chunkSize] chunkSize, max]]
    ]
```

`chunkFold` function folds given function `f` over subsequent "chunks" of data generated by `getChunk` function. `getChunk[i, j]` should give list of elements with indices from `i` to `j`. In total function uses indices from `min` to `max` in chunks of given `chunkSize`. Example of "symbolic" usage:

```
chunkFold[f, x, {3, 20, 5, getChunk}]
(* f[f[f[f[x, getChunk[3, 7]], getChunk[8, 12]], getChunk[13, 17]], getChunk[18, 20]] *)
```

In some problems, like one in OP, chunk size can be used not only to control memory usage, but also to limit size of intermediate results, that can decide whether it's enough to use machine numbers and packed arrays, or whether non-machine numbers must be used.

---

Let's define simple helper function, giving timing and memory usage together with result of evaluation of given expression:

```
timeMem = Function[,
    Module[{result}, Prepend[AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[result = #], result]],
    HoldFirst
];
```

Now let's use our `chunkFold` function for problem from OP:

```
chunkFold[#1 + Tr@Power[#2, 2] &, 0, {1, 10^8, 900, Range}] // timeMem
(* {333333338333333350000000, 0.969158, 18024} *)
```

result is calculated in one second using 18 kilobytes of memory. Which can be compared to simple `Do`, looping trough individual elements:

```
Module[{out = 0, i}, Do[out += i^2, {i, 10^8}]; out] // timeMem
(* {333333338333333350000000, 58.9343, 1112} *)
```

that uses one minute and one kilobyte.

---

Let's check how speed and memory usage of different solutions depends on total number of elements. We'll test three functions: `do` is simple iteration over every element, `trPower` is fully vectorized, `trPowerChunk` is intermediate solution using vectorized functions on chunks of 900 elements.

```
do[n_] := Module[{out = 0, i}, Do[out += i^2, {i, n}]; out]
trPower[n_] := Tr[Range[1, n]^2]
trPowerChunk[n_] := chunkFold[#1 + Tr@Power[#2, 2] &, 0, {1, n, 900, Range}]
```

[image: Time and memory benchmarks]

We see that `do` is slowest, but has constant, lowest, usage of memory.

`trPower` is fastest up to around `3*10^6`, when as [explained by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127683/14303) numbers become to large to be stored as machine integers and *Mathematica* starts unpacking lists. Memory usage is proportional to number of elements, with larger proportionality constant after unpacking starts.

`trPowerChunk` is almost as fast as `trPower` before the latter starts unpacking, and fastest afterward. Memory usage of `trPowerChunk` grows up to `n = 900`, which was chosen as chunk size, and is constant afterward. From `101176707` sum of squares of consecutive `900` integers is larger than largest machine integer, so *Mathematica* starts unpacking arrays and we see jump in both time and memory usage. Memory usage is still constant, after unpacking, but this constant is higher.

Answer (score 6):

```
ParallelSum[i^2, {i, 100000000}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.128204, 333333338333333350000000}`

---

The parallelized version of the `Do` loop in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127659/18476) by [corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22013/corey979):

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ParallelEvaluate[out = 0];
 ParallelDo[out += i^2, {i, 100000000}];
 Total@ParallelEvaluate[out]
 ]
```

> `{35.3163, 333333338333333350000000}`

Comment: You should add alo the timing for an unparallelized `Do` loop for comparison. I got a 3.5 times increase on a 4 core machine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why I missed this question, but the `` Streaming` `` framework computes this out of the box. Unfortunately, it has to be patched in modern versions of Mathematica, so I refer to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154456/81) for a patch. Assuming that that code has been executed, let us create a lazy range:

```
lr = Streaming`ListAPI`Lazy`LazyRange[1, 100000000]
```

Then check its length:

```
Length @ lr

(* 100000000 *)
```

And finally:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Total[Map[#^2 &, lr]]]

(* {18.63, 333333338333333350000000}  *)
```

and

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

(* 236753504 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

using NSum,  the totoal timing is pretty fast, and you can even calculate larger numbers without memory issues.

```
    AbsoluteTiming@NSum[i^2, {i, 1, 100000000}]
```

````
{0.003697, 3.33333*10^23}
```
````