# Dot product of lists with non-equal dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

I have two lists, `er` and `ns`:

```
Dimensions@er
Dimensions@ns
```

gives:

```
{343, 3}
{343, 3996, 3}
```

I want to do a dot product such that in loops it is:

```
For [i = 1, i <= 343, i++
  For j = 1, j <= 3996, j++
    result[[i,j]] = er[[i]].ns[[i,j]]
  ]
]
```

So I was thinking:

```
MapThread[Function[{x, y}, ((x.#) & /@ y)], {er, ns}]
```

Because

```
(er[[1]].#)&/@ns[[1]]
```

works fine.

But this is not it. Also I would like to parallelize it, and I do not know how well `MapThread` is paralelizable.

Comment: (Almost) never use `For`; use `Do`, `Table`, `While` etc. In this case I'd suggest `ParallelDo` (maybe with `ParallelEvaluate`; see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127670/22013)).

Comment: @corey979 I do not use `For`, I simply mentioned it because it is absolutely obvious with that notation what I want to do. I am trying to do it with `Map` and others, it is written in the question though...

Comment: Well, that wasn't entirely clear to me, and when I see a `For` I automatically discourage from using it.

Comment: Why `MapThread` "is not it"? What's wrong with it? It's correct, and the fastest among the methods here.

Comment: As a dot product: `Transpose[er.Transpose[ns, {2, 3, 1}], {1, 1, 2}]`.

Answer (score 4):

The straghtforward way is

```
ans1 = Table[er[[i]].ns[[i, j]], {i, 343}, {j, 3996}]
```

on my Macbook Pro this gives an `AbsoluteTiming` of 0.611 seconds. Using `ParallelTable` cuts that time in half if multiple kernels are already launched.

I always feel that using vectorized operations gives much bigger boosts to speed than parallellization does, so here is what I came up with:

```
ans2 = Block[{erCopies, erT, nsT},
 erCopies = ConstantArray[#, 3996] & /@ er;
 erT = Transpose[erCopies, {2, 3, 1}];
 nsT = Transpose[ns, {2, 3, 1}];
 Plus @@ (erT*nsT)
 ];
```

This uses more RAM than the straightforward way because it enlarges `er` to match the dimensions of `ns`, but is a bit faster for me, 0.177 seconds. Note that I could not afford to run these timings on a completely fresh kernel, so the timings may not be reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

First, some data:

```
er = RandomReal[1, {343, 3}];
ns = RandomReal[1, {343, 3996, 3}];
```

A compiled, auto-parallelized way, which is quite fast:

```
cf = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, {w, _Real, 1}},
  v.w,
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
  ];

(result = cf[er, ns]) // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.04556, {343, 3996}}  *)
```

An array-based approach, which is somewhat faster than the OP's `MapThread` code:

```
(result2 = MapThread[Dot, {er, #}] & /@ Transpose[ns, {2, 1, 3}] // Transpose) //
      Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.147916, {343, 3996}}  *)

result2 == result
(*  True  *)
```

OP's:

```
MapThread[Function[{x, y}, ((x.#) & /@ y)], {er, ns}] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.376943, {343, 3996}}  *)
```

Marius's solutions:

```
Table[er[[i]].ns[[i, j]], {i, 343}, {j, 3996}] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.855036, {343, 3996}}  *)

ans2 = Block[{erCopies, erT, nsT}, 
    erCopies = ConstantArray[#, 3996] & /@ er;
    erT = Transpose[erCopies, {2, 3, 1}];
    nsT = Transpose[ns, {2, 3, 1}];
    Plus @@ (erT*nsT)]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.149258, Null}  *)
```