# Breaking "Functional Loops" and Doing Lazy Evaluation In Mathematica

Tags: functional-style, lazy-computations

Alright, so this is a question about the functional way to break a for/while loop. Since we're on the Mathematica SE, I'm interested in the ways a Mathematica vet would handle this, however the question is similar in spirit to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363318/what-are-the-functional-equivalents-of-imperative-break-statements-and-other-loo) question. I am also interested in lazy evaluation in Mathematica.

For instance, consider writing an algorithm to detect whether an array is monotonic or not. How could I rewrite the algorithm below so that it

- does not check the entire array and,
- does not store the entire `input` array in memory?

```
n = 1000;
input = {5, 4, 3}~Join~Range[1, n];
AllTrue[Differences[input], # >= 0 &] || AllTrue[Differences[input], # <= 0 &]
```

In Python 3+, one way to do this is shown below. All the operations below work on an iterator level, so only the necessary elements are computed. You can test this by setting `n=100000000` and compare to the algorithm above.

```py
from itertools import chain, islice, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
  "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
  a, b = tee(iterable)
  return zip(a, islice(b, 1, None))

def isMonotonic(iterable):
  pw_iterable = pairwise(iterable)
  all_increasing = all(x <= y for x, y in pw_iterable)
  all_decreasing = all(x >= y for x, y in pw_iterable)
  return all_decreasing or all_increasing

n = 1000
arr = chain([5,4,3], range(1, n+1)) # obviously, non-monotonic
print(isMonotonic(arr))
```

I hope I've made clear my broader set of questions about computations in which a loop should be allowed to terminate early and the later elements in the list need not be computed. I would love to see how this would be done in an idiomatic Mathematica way.

---

@xzczd's hint to look at the lazy-computations tag helped me find [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/838/functional-style-using-lazy-lists). TL;DR: there have been a number of attempts at implementing lazy functionality. These two appear to be the most up-to-date:

- [lazyLists](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1467915) package
- [Streaming](https://github.com/lshifr/StreamingPatch) package (doesn't appear to be actively maintained, but a [comment in 2019 by L. Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204948/34831) reports it may get more attention); see an [introductory post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85278/is-there-a-built-in-equivalent-to-pythons-enumerate/85336#85336)

Comment: "…ideally, does not store the entire input array in memory", as to this part, you may want to check posts under the tag [tag:lazy-computations].

Comment: Use AnyTrue and invert the condition, which will break early, not AllTrue - as this would check all elements.

Comment: I think AnyTrue is unnecessary, since AllTrue can exit early once it sees at least one False.

Comment: I suppose you are right - it's 4am here an I must be losing it.

Comment: No worries, I've definitely been there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my [lazyLists package](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1467915) mentioned by the OP, you would do something like this to find out if a list is monotonic:

```
<< lazyLists`
n = 100000;
(* lazy representation of the example input *)
input = lazyCatenate[{{3, 4, 2}, lazyGenerator[# &, 1, 1, n, 1]}];
monotonicQ[lz_lazyList, test_] := Catch[
 FoldList[
   If[TrueQ @ test[#2, #1], #2, Throw[False, "nonmonotonic"]]&,
   lz
 ][[-1]]; (* taking the last part iterates through the lazyList *)
 True
 ,
 "nonmonotonic"
];
monotonicQ[input, Greater]
```

> False

You can also use `partitionedLazyList` to generate elements in batches, which is usually faster for long arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Applying DeMorgan's law to the logic simplifies things a bit:

```
With[{ d = Differences[input] },
 Nand[AnyTrue[d, # < 0 &], AnyTrue[d, # > 0 &]]
]
```

The *idiomatic™* way to solve this is with `SequenceCases` to report the first case where an element is smaller than the previous one:

```
ismontoneinc[list_] := SequenceCases[list, {x_, y_} /; y < x, 1] == {}
ismontonedec[list_] := SequenceCases[list, {x_, y_} /; y > x, 1] == {}
ismonotone[list_] := ismontoneinc[list] || ismontonedec[list]
```

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6}; ismonotone[data]
(* result: False - not monotone *)

data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; ismonotone[data]
(* result: True - monotone *) 

data = {5,3,2,0}; ismonotone[data]
(* result: True - monotone *)
```

**However**, this has hopelessly bad performance with a million random integers in v12.1.1. and terrible memory usage too. Just try `ismonotone[RandomReal[1, 100000]]` - it clearly doesn't even break early which is very disappointing. I guess *Mathematica* is full of surprises.

Comment: @xzczd the question's Mathematica code was updated to note this, I've edited it.

Comment: The documentation for AllTrue says "AllTrue[list,test] and AllTrue[list,test,level] only evaluate as many test[Subscript[e, i]] as are necessary to determine the result", so I doubt the DeMorgan's laws are necessary.

Can you say something about the need to load the data list into memory? Can that be avoided?

Comment: AllTrue must check all the elements in this particular case - AnyTrue only needs to find one counterexample to terminate, so yes it does help here.

Comment: Maybe, I'm confused, but that doesn't seem right. See my comment on the question thread.

Comment: @dskeletov the memory usage is awful and the performance is terrible.

Comment: Well, ok, thank you for SequenceCases, but I was aware of the poor performance in the OP.

Comment: @dskeletov no, your code is faster than mine , SequenceCases is much slower at scale I'm finding. It also doesn't seem to break early with large lists which must be a bug of some kind.